# Developer Console Overwhelmed by Logs

Tags: developer-console, debug-logs

So my developer console is overwhelmed by logs. I have a fair amount of regularly running (light) processes that overwhelm the web Sockets. It makes it very difficult in production to look into issues. So my questions are:

1. Will reducing the logs levels solve this (meaning will salesforce send less data over the websocket)?
2. If so, what would be a recommend configuration?
3. Anybody have any other ideas for solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will reducing the logs levels solve this (meaning will salesforce send less data over the websocket)?

No.

> Anybody have any other ideas for solving this problem?

Create a different user for yourself. Typically integration users should not be the same user an admin uses, especially for debugging production.

Comment: This would involve paying for another license too or is there something I don't realize?

Comment: @LaytonEverson If you have a user that doesn't need to be active, you could temporarily deactivate them, do whatever you need to do, then reactive them later. Otherwise, you could also ask salesforce.com for a courtesy license; they may choose to provide one to you one at their discretion. Having a dedicated API user is something that many larger organizations end up doing sooner or later. For example, we have a handful of licenses we use explicitly for integrations out of our 7,000+ licenses.

Comment: Thank you for the advice